# Why is the modal button calling multiple times?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I write a code for update button click that will show a bootstrap modal with 2 buttons cancel, delete.I noticed that after clicking `update` button the modal display with button.however if i press `delete` button on that modal then strangely the  `delete` button call it self twice or more instead on 1.As a result the ajax is also firing twice.I thing there may be any event class.Here the sample code.

```
    <button type="button"   id="update" class="btn btn-success" style="display:none;">Update</button>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" id="btn-delete">Delete</button>
</div>

$("#update").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#confirm-delete').modal("show");
}); 

$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
     var instance = $(this);
     $("#btn-delete").click(function(event) {

         var data_x = 101;
         event.preventDefault();
         instance.modal('hide');
         $.ajax({
             url: 'delete_data.php',
             type: "post",
             async: true,
             data: ({
                 data_x: data_x
             }),
             success: function(data) {
                 alert(data);
             }
         });


     });

 });
```

please help me to understand it & resolve it.thanks

Comment: Are you sure you aren't attaching the event handler twice? i.e. show modal=>attach handler=>hide modal=>show modal=>attach handler(uh-oh, 2 handlers).  In which case, you need to reorganize things to only execute the attach-handler code once.

Comment: does this happen all the time that it call it twice or sometimes it call it more?

Comment: and are you sure that $("#update").click(function (e) { is not called twice?

Comment: Off topic: You probably don't need to `preventDefault` on a button.

Answer (score 4):

You're creating an additional click function every time you open the modal. Do it once:

```
$('#confirm-delete').one('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
// --------------------^
     $("#btn-delete").click(function(event) {
```

Alternatively, use event delegation and do it outside the modal callback (anywhere inside `document.ready`):

```
$(document).on('click', '#confirm-delete', function() {
    // ...
```

Comment: Hello @isherwood. Thanks for your reply.I tried what you suggested.but still it not working.please help

Comment: You tried which? Either should work. Maybe create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the problem.